# API not returning 401 instead returning Identity Login page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have an api and a web app on the same application. I try to access a resource which is located at the API, but when authorization fails, it redirects to the Identity page. I have checked up on other solutions but their approach is different from my own approach. I'm injecting it into the services container. When I put a break-point over the code, it doesn't even reach the point at all

```
services.AddAuthentication()
.AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                x.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnTokenValidated = context =>
                    {
                        var userService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<SchoolAuthenticationManager>();
                        var userName = context.Principal.Identity.Name;
                        var user = userService.FindByNameAsync(userName);
                        if (user == null)
                        {
                            // return unauthorized if user no longer exists
                            context.Fail("Unauthorized user access.");
                        }
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnAuthenticationFailed = failed =>
                    {
                        failed.Fail("Unauthorized user access.");
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };

            });
```

This is my full `ConfigureServices` method

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" +
                "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;

                options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 0;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                options.Password.RequireDigit = false;

                options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
                options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
                options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 4;

                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;

            });

            services.AddCors();
            services.AddDbContext<ElectDbContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ElectDatabase"))
            .UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking));

            services.AddMvc()
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
                .AddJsonOptions(options=>
                {
                    options.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
                    //options.SerializerSettings.Culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.ShortDatePattern;
                    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver();
                    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
                });

            services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                x.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnTokenValidated = context =>
                    {
                        var userService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ElectAuthenticationManager>();
                        var userName = context.Principal.Identity.Name;
                        var user = userService.FindByNameAsync(userName);
                        if (user == null)
                        {
                            // return unauthorized if user no longer exists
                            context.Fail("Unauthorized user access.");
                        }
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnAuthenticationFailed = failed =>
                    {
                        failed.Fail("Unauthorized user access.");
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                x.SaveToken = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidIssuer = (string)Configuration.GetSection("JwtIssuerOptions").GetValue(typeof(string), "Issuer"),
                    ValidAudience = (string)Configuration.GetSection("JwtIssuerOptions").GetValue(typeof(string), "Audience"),
                    TokenDecryptionKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0),
                };
            });
            services.AddIdentityCore<ElectUser>()
                .AddRoles<ElectRole>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ElectDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultUI(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.UIFramework.Bootstrap4);

        }
```

Ive also tried this but still does not work

```
 services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents()
                {
                    OnRedirectToReturnUrl = (response) =>
                    {
                        if(response.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api") && response.RedirectUri == "https://localhost:44307/Identity/Account/Login")
                        {
                            response.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                        }
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnRedirectToLogin = (response) =>
                    {
                        if (response.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api") && response.Response.StatusCode == 200)
                        {
                            response.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                        }
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnRedirectToAccessDenied = (response) =>
                    {
                        if (response.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api") && response.Response.StatusCode == 200)
                        {
                            response.Response.StatusCode = 403;
                        }
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            });
```

Comment: The calls that add Identity at the end of `ConfigureServices` cause this behaviour. This sets the default schemes around Identity and overrides those set in your `AddAuthentication` call.

Comment: so is there no workaround to this? My application needs an identity store of course!

Comment: Yeah, it can certainly be done. You can move the `AddAuthentication` call down below `AddIdentityCore`, which will make JwtBearer the default. However, you want to support multiple schemes, which is covered in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Comment: Okay @KirkLarkin I need to apply your solution before i continue

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem by following @KirkLarkin suggestion at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-3.1 
I have changed my app to use two authentication schemes and i have also specified the authentication scheme in the `Authroize` attribute of the controller.